# JLayeredPane objects showing from an "hidden" panel

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

I have a problem with Java Swing, in particular with JLayeredPane.
I have a Deck manager which contains 4 JPanels in a JLayeredPane, but when i add an object to a Pane, then switch to another, the objects turns invisible at first, but when i pass with the mouse on, it returns visible even thoug i'm on a different Panel, here's the code:

```
deckSelector = new JLayeredPane();                                                          

    Point origin = new Point(30, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        Deck deck = new Deck(types[i], colors[i], origin);
        deckSelector.add(deck, i);
        decks[i] = deck;
    }
```

to change

```
int j = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    for(int i=0; i<types.length; i++){  
        if(selectors[i].isSelected()){
        deckSelector.setLayer(decks[i], 3);
                found = true;
                j=2;
            } else 
            if(!selectors[i].isSelected()){
                deckSelector.setLayer(decks[i], j);
                if(found) j--;
                else j++;
            };
            }
```

to add a card:

```
Card btnNewButton = new Card("Name Card");
    add(btnNewButton);
```

I have a deck manager which is the main JLayerdPane, it has 4 decks overlayed, in which i can add cards, but when i switch from a deck to another, the card is still visible. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

> but when i pass with the mouse on

A mouseOver event is generate for the component. In the case of a JButton the border is changed, so the component needs to repaint itself. So that is why the component becomes visible.

The point of using a JLayeredPane is to see all the layers at the same time. Its just that some components will be stacked on top of others.

If you only want to see a single panel at a time, then you should be using a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). Then you can swap which panel is visible and any given time.

If you think you really need to use a JLayeredPane then try using setVisible(false) on the panel you don't want to see. This should prevent events from being passed to components on the panel in that layer.

Comment: Thank you for the help, i wanted to use the JLayeredPane bc i wanted to swap between panes from buttons pretty far from the pane itself, and a card layout has the buttons attached to the panes, i'd have used that otherwise. I'll try with the setVisible(false).

Comment: @GabLog, `and a card layout has the buttons attached to the panes` - no it doesn't it you don't design it that way. You obviously didn't read the tutorial or download the code and test the example code.

Comment: @GabLog,  I was simply stating a fact. You stated that a `CardLayout` has the buttons attached to the panes. That is completely not true so I correctly your statement and told you to read the tutorial on `CardLayout`. I have absolutely no idea where "tabbed pane" came into the conversation. I never mentioned it in my answer. I'm not a mind reader. I don't know what you intend to say and I can only base my comments on your actual statements. And based on your statement you did not understand how a `CardLayout` worked. So I took extra time to clarify the problem. That is called being helpful!

Comment: @GabLog, and don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark beside the answer so people know the problem has been solved.